# Using `Real32` numbers in Mathematica?

Tags: performance-tuning

Is it possible to use `Real32` format in Mathematica for matrix operations and does it make sense for performance?

For high-dimensional vectors, high precision is an overkill (neural nets use float16 nowadays), and modern CPUs can process `float32` at twice the speed of `float64`. For instance, trying to optimize the code below, I see that half the time is spent in float64 matrix operations

```
SeedRandom[Method -> "MKL"];
d = 1000;
B = 1000;
a = 2/(d + 1);

step[w_, x_] = w - a x x . w;
sample := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {B, d}];
batchStep[W_] := MapThread[step, {W, sample}];
Nest[batchStep, sample, 100]; // AbsoluteTiming (* 1.36 *)
```

Comment: You can define the sample to be a `NumericArray` with lower-precision real numbers, but I assume it would not work with `MapThread` or `Nest`